# Running a shell script from any (non-specific) directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shebang

so I've already found this asked here few other times, but I didn't quite comprehend the answer.

So I'm running on a giant server for multiple people, so the directories are a bit wonky and I'm having bit of an issue figuring out what I'm supposed to do.

So I've wanted to created my own script

did the following

```
$ mkdir myscripts
$ cd myscripts
$ vim dirstatus.sh
```

Inside the dirstatus.sh I just wrote a simple script, I'm more of interested in making the script executable from any directory.

So

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# My own script - Experimenting with Shell
# Setting path export
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/myscripts
printf "The current directory is $(pwd) \n
Path of this script is $(PATH)"
```

afterwards I did

`$ chmod +x dirstatus.sh`

When I do ./dirstatus.sh inside the myscripts directory it works

However when I do `$ dirstatus` in any other directory or even inside the myscripts directory as well

I get the following error

`~ksh: dirstat: command not found`

Any solutions?

Comment: could you store an alias in `~/.bashrc` instead?

Comment: "When I do /dirstatus.sh inside the myscripts directory it works": Impossible, this will always execute `/dirstatus.sh` at the root directory

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Maybe he just forgot to paste the full stop (or he's actually placed the script in root but I doubt it)

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano @jDo Yes apologies, that was a spelling/formatting error. Meant to write when I do `./dirstatus.sh`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the myscripts directory that contains the dirstatus.sh file is not in the path for your terminal session.  Assuming that you made the myscripts directory inside of your home, you can do the following:

```
PATH=~/myscripts:$PATH
```

To make this change work on all new terminal sessions, you can add the above to the ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile files that are loaded on login.

Comment: That's sort of where I am lost

Since this is (as mentioned) not a personal server, whenever I connect onto it i get placed in a specific directory eg.

home/users/me
however the home directory is off the limits for me.

Therefore I am not sure, if I am supposed to create a new .bash_profile file inside where I get connected or what.

Comment: Generally, whenever you are put when you first log into the server is your home directory.  You can also run `echo $HOME` to see the environment variable for your home directory.

Comment: Tilde expansion is not supported by `sh` (though Bash supports it even in POSIX mode). You should use `$HOME` for portability.

Comment: @Jenos Alright, i can confirm it is where i connect, through usage of `echo $HOME` however when I do ls -la there is no .bashrc .bash_profile .profile or anything of similar sorts present. Moreover even if I create one, it still refuses to work outside of launch through ./dirstatus.sh in the script's location

Comment: @Rawrplus Did you log into a new session after creating the profile file?  It will only load on login, otherwise you would have to run `source ~/.bash_profile`.